# Undefined method for main:Object (NoMethodError) though method is defined

Tags: ruby

I have defined a script with the following code snippet:

```
check_params param

def check_params(param)
 # some code
end
```

When I run this I get

> undefined method `check_params' for main:Object (NoMethodError)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Ruby expects the method to be declared before you call it, try to move your method definition before you call the method like:

```
def check_params(param)
 # some code
end

check_params param
```